# how to remove swap button icons for limited time in angular 16

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I just want to make a function to remove an icon inside a button to be replaced with a spinner that is already added by primeng so just function to rm the child

the button:

```html
<p-button label="" [loading]="loading" (onClick)="load()" (onClick)="rm()">
  <i id="rm_icon" class="pi pi-user-plus"></i>
</p-button>
```

As you see `rm()` is the function and I want it to remove the existing button icon, but only while the loading spinner icon is displayed.

I only know how to remove it forever, I am not really good with TypeScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer i just needed if condition so it removes and adds the icon if it true or flase

```
<p-button [icon]=" loading ?   'pi pi-spinner pi-spin' : 'pi pi-user-plus'"
label="Add" (onClick)="load()" > </p-button>
```

the typescript:

```
    loading: boolean = false;

load() {
    this.loading = true;

    setTimeout(() => {
        this.loading = false
    }, 2000);
}
```

}